# how to support multiple screens in a Android theme

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an Android theme aka launcher. I have my first page ready to go but my question is how can I add additional screens so the user can swipe to them. I tried googling but with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is greatly dependent on the structure of your views.  Have you used `Fragment`s?

If you've used `Fragment`s for your current view, you can create `Fragment`s for the other ones and simply put them all in a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

I'd recommend checking out this [training session](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).